# Get -fPIE linker errors on RedHat, but not Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, redhat, ld

I'm converting a 32-bit app to 64-bit on Ubuntu 20.04.  Was able to build and run it on a RedHat (actually Amazon Linux) system, but when I try to compile it in 64-bit mode on Ubuntu, I get this error from the linker (works fine in 32-bit mode):

```
/usr/bin/ld: /u/apps/lib/libiodbc.a(connect.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `iodbcdm_global_lock' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
```

libiodbc.a is a version of the odbc driver loader that I got pre-compiled from OpenLink (because I couldn't find a package with a 32-bit version).  Openlink gave me both 32- and 64-bit versions.  Didn't recompile it, but it worked as delivered on RedHat - just not Ubuntu.  And the 32-bit version of that library linked fine on Ubuntu.

Is there some setting on RedHat that defaults all compilation to 'position-independent executable' mode, with that setting different on Ubuntu (20.04)?  I suppose I could go back and add -fPIE to my global compiler flags (would that solve this?), but I'm wondering why Ubuntu is complaining while RedHat didn't.

Also, I have used -fPIC before for shared libraries, but never used -fPIE.  If I build everything with -fPIE, is -fPIC redundant?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind (kind of).  Since Ubuntu *does* provide a 64-bit version of libiodbc.a in package libiodbc2-dev, I installed that, and that version links okay.  Oh.  And on RedHat, the distro's 64-bit library was already installed, and it was getting picked up from there - so I guess the OpenLink 64-bit version was never successfully linked in anywhere.

I guess my question still kind of stands.  Is it that the 64-bit library I got from OpenLink was compiled with a -fPIE flag that made it incompatible with my own code compiled locally?  Should I be using -fPIE for everything?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe that RedHat has configured GCC to default to PIE, as a way of improving overall security of the system. When compiled with PIE, the kernel can load the program at a random address (Address Space Randomization, ASR) each time, so that attacks that rely on a certain address space layout can be thwarted.

Given that you have a pre-compiled object that was apparently not compiled with PIE, you'll need to link with `-no-pie` (and you may as well compile the rest of your code with `-fno-pie`).

No, `-fPIC` is not redundant with `-fPIE`. When compiling code for a shared library, it must be PIC, which imposes more constraints on the generated code than PIE does. You can use either `-fPIC` or `-fPIE` for the main program code and still build a position-independent executable, but you must use `-fPIC` for shared library code.

Comment: Interesting.  I think Ubuntu defaults to PIE too, since I occasionally have had to use -no-pie to get apps to work when they store pointers along with state data to be used across multiple invocations.  But yeah, the library must've been built the opposite of how my locally compiled objects were built...